# Manually dying mulch

Tags: mulch

I have a pretty big yard with a lot of old trees, as a result I own a wood chipper and produce a fairly hefty volume of mulch (several yards a year).  I use the mulch in my gardens but for the decorative ones I would prefer an evenly colored mulch as mine is pretty non-uniform due to the variety of trees and shrubbery it comes from.

In googling most of what I have found online is instructions for spraying already laid mulch that has lost its color.  I have only found a couple things about dying raw mulch, and have found nobody talking about how to choose the dye or even where to buy it at all.

Does anybody have any experience in dying raw homemade wood chips?  Where can I purchase the dye and what should I be looking for.

I envision using a plastic kiddie pool since I have a pretty large quantity of mulch.